# How to vertically align a table column both top and bottom?

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7, html-table, vertical-alignment, internet-explorer-6

..if the columns height is dependent on the height of another column?
Solution should work on IE6,7 and Mozilla at least.

HTML table layout:

```
 +------------------------+----------------------+
 | top-aligned paragraph  |     Here             |
 |                        |     is a             |
 |                        |     very             |
 |                        |     long             |
 |                        |     text             |
 |                        |     that             |
 |                        |     eventually       |
 |                        |     determines       |
 |                        |     the overall      |
 |bottom-aligned paragraph|     table height.    |
 +------------------------+----------------------+
```

Answer (score 12):

The easiest way should be to just use `vertical-align` top and bottom in the cells that you wish to align:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="top">
<p>Top aligned paragraph</p>
</td>
<td rowspan="2">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer id egestas condimentum neque elit. Non tortor tempus orci quis condimentum interdum dictum pede Duis enim. Sociis sollicitudin Nulla lacinia risus id sit odio pellentesque Vestibulum et. Ipsum pretium vestibulum et lobortis mauris semper In In id faucibus. Est Integer Curabitur dui Quisque eu habitasse Curabitur gravida vel semper. A libero vel nisl.</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="bottom">
<p>Bottom aligned paragraph</p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and then the CSS:

```
.top{
vertical-align:top;
}
.bottom{
vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

Copy|Paste away

Comment: Just wanted to add my 5 cents. In some versions of Odoo(for example Odoo 9.0) using the "valign", but using "vertical-align" will do the job. Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 3):

Use the rowspan attribute (http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/tables/index_famsupp_30.html) to make the long text (column2) span two rows.  Then put the Para1 in the first column first row (align top), then Para2 in the first column second row (align bottom).

```
--------------------------------------
|Para 1 Align Top |This is your very |                   
|                 |long text.  This  |
|                 |is your very long |
|_________________|text.             |
|                 |This is your very |
|                 |long text.  This  |
|                 |is your very long |
|Para2 align bottm|Text.             |
--------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don’t want to use tables, you could do something like this:

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    .outer {
        position: relative;
        background-color: #EEE;
    }
    .right {
        width: 50%;
        margin-left: 50%;
        background-color: #F88;
    }
    .top,
    .bottom {
        position: absolute;
        width: 50%;
    }
    .top {
        top: 0;
        background-color: #8F8;
    }
    .bottom {
        bottom: 0;
        background-color: #88F;
    }
</style>

<div class="outer">
    <div class="right">Here<br>is a<br>very<br>long<br>text<br>that<br>eventually<br>determines<br>the overall<br>table height.</div>
    <div class="top">top-aligned paragraph</div>
    <div class="bottom">bottom-aligned paragraph</div>
</div>
```